# Statistical definitions of Random class in C#

Tags: c#, random, statistics

I know that the Random class in C# / .NET create a PseudoRandom numbers.

First, I would like to know what function does the computer use after taking the time from the CPU to make a seed?

Second, What is the Variance, Expected value and the Standard deviation of this Random.next() function?

Thanks!

Comment: For seeding, see the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca . Note that this is an implementation detail, and it's different between .NET Framework and .NET Core

Comment: This boils down to finding documentation about `Random`, which is off-topic on Stack.

Comment: I don´t know why you care for this. Anyway I doubt you will get any reliable information about that despite the **current** source-code. However there´s no guarantee that will allways stay the same and thus it may change in future versions of .NET. The only guarantee you get is that `Random` creates random numbers within a specified range. How random this ctually is and how it´s computed, is an implementaion-detail you shouldn´t depend on.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I did not find an answer for those quastions on the internet, so I think that stackOverFlow can help me with that. If this is not the right place, I apologize and ask to delete the post

Comment: @HimBromBeere I try to create synthetic data and use a lot of this Random.next() function, so I wanted to know that it was reliable enough.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8 . That references the source of the algorithm.